# Get-WmiObject not showing desired results while filtering for PNPDeviceID

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.2

I have been trying to get a script working that identifies whether the graphics card currently installed in a Windows 10 system is an Nvidia card or not via the hardwareID. But for whatever reason I can't get it to grab only the PNPDeviceID line that I want. I have setup 2 different test scripts in an attempt to get this working:

```
$VideoCardID = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_VideoController | Where-Object { $_.PNPDeviceID -like "PCI\VEN_10DE*"}
Write-Host $VideoCardID
Write-Host "Press any key to exit..."
$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
exit
```

Which outputs: `\\DESKTOP-UPTIVUP\root\cimv2:Win32_VideoController.DeviceID="VideoController1" Press any key to exit...`

And the other one:

```
$VideoCardID = Get-WmiObject -Class CIM_VideoController PNPDeviceID | Where-Object { $_."PCI\VEN_10DE*"}
Write-Host $VideoCardID
Write-Host "Press any key to exit..."
$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
exit
```

Which just outputs `Press any key to exit...`

The desired result would be that it only detects the hardwareID (aka the PNPDeviceID) of the grafics card an then through and `if/else` statement figures out if its an Nvidia model or not.

I have been trying for some days now to figure out what's going wrong, but at this point I have given up, hence I am here to ask for advice.
This might be quite simple to solve for people with alot of experince with Powershell, although I'm still a script kiddie at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first snippet, you just need to use dot notation to reference the `PNPDeviceID` property of the object `$VideoCardID`:

```
Write-Host $VideoCardID.PNPDeviceID
```

The reason why you see the `_PATH` property is because `Write-Host` is stringifying your object, something similar to what would happen if we call the `.ToString()` method on this object:

```
PS /> $VideoCardID.ToString()
\\computername\root\cimv2:Win32_VideoController.DeviceID="VideoController1"
```

On your second snippet, your `Where-Object` statement is incorrect:

```
Where-Object { $_."PCI\VEN_10DE*"}
```

Should be the same as your first example:

```
Where-Object { $_.PNPDeviceID -like "PCI\VEN_10DE*"}
```

As for how you can approach the code with an `if` / `else` statement:

```
if((Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_VideoController).PNPDeviceID -like "PCI\VEN_10DE*") {
    "It's NVIDIA!"
}
else {
    "It's not NVIDIA!"
}
```

As aside, it is recommended to use the [CIM cmdlets](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets/) instead of WMI.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I did read something about CIM being the best thing to use because its newer and such.